# Scipy Minimization TNC Working, But Not CG

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, minimization

I'm trying to complete [week 4 the Machine Learning course on Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/home/week/4). The assingment uses the [MINST data](https://s3.amazonaws.com/spark-public/ml/exercises/on-demand/machine-learning-ex3.zip) for multi-class classification.

The dimensions are X (5000,401), y (5000,1), theta (10,401), which start off as arrays. X was inserted with 1's on the first feature column.

My cost and gradient functions are below:

```
def sigmoid(z):
    g = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))
    return g

def lrCostFunction(theta, X, y, my_lambda):
    m = float(len(X))
    theta = np.matrix(theta)
    X = np.matrix(X)
    y = np.matrix(y)

    #cost function:
    term1 = np.multiply(-y,np.log(sigmoid(X*theta.T)))
    term2 = np.multiply((1-y),np.log(1-sigmoid(X*theta.T)))
    reg = np.power(theta[:,1:theta.shape[1]],2)
    J = np.sum(term1-term2)/m + (my_lambda/(2.0*m) * np.sum(reg))    
    return J

def gradient (theta, X, y, my_lambda):
    m = float(len(X))
    theta = np.matrix(theta)
    X = np.matrix(X)
    y = np.matrix(y)

    #gradient:
    error = sigmoid(X * theta.T) - y
    g = (X.T * error /(m)).T + ((my_lambda/m) * theta)
    g[0,0] = np.sum(np.multiply(error, X[:,0])) / m    
    return g
```

Here is my One vs All classification function with the TNC optimization:

```
def oneVsAll(X, y, num_labels, my_lambda):
    m = float(X.shape[0])
    n = float(X.shape[1])-1
    all_theta = np.zeros((num_labels,n+1))
    for K in range(1, num_labels + 1):
        theta = np.zeros(n+1)
        y_logical = np.array([1 if j == K else 0 for j in y]).reshape(m,1)
        opt_theta = opt.minimize(fun=lrCostFunction, x0=theta, \
                             args=(X,y_logical,my_lambda), \
                             method='TNC', jac=gradient).x
        all_theta[K-1,:] = opt_theta
    return all_theta
```

When I try to run CG however, it returns the error at line 8: "shapes (1,401) and (1,401) not aligned: 401 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)":

```
    def oneVsAll(X, y, num_labels, my_lambda):
        m = float(X.shape[0])
        n = float(X.shape[1])-1
        all_theta = np.zeros((num_labels,n+1))
        for K in range(1, num_labels + 1):
            theta = np.zeros(n+1)
            y_logical = np.array([1 if j == K else 0 for j in y]).reshape(m,1)
            opt_theta = opt.fmin_cg(f=lrCostFunction, x0=theta, \
                                    fprime=gradient, \
                                    args=(X,y_logical,my_lambda))
            all_theta[K-1,:] = opt_theta
        return all_theta
```

I saw elsewhere that CG only likes 1-d vectors from y. If I try to flatten y or reduce its dimension, however, everything else breaks. Is it generally a bad idea to use np.matrix as oppose to use np.dot with arrays? I like being able to easily transpose with matrixes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which line is the problem at? That seems like a matrix multiplication problem. Do you know how matrix multiplication works?

Comment: I think using `np.matrix` has a lot of booby traps for not many advantages. You can do everything using `np.arrays` only. Just use `np.dot` for matrix multiplication, `*` is otherwise elementwise multiplication.

Comment: @Julien how about np.ndarray?

Comment: yes, the same...